# How to fix "Please login as the user "xx" rather than the user "root" on azure ubuntu 1804 vm?

Tags: ssh, root, authentication

I create an azure ubuntu 1804 vm with no root user and ssh public key.

Then I try to use the script of [how to enable root ssh public key login with no root account and sshpass and sudo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/551876/how-to-enable-root-ssh-public-key-login-with-no-root-account-and-sshpass-and-sud)

But I got the problem of "Please login as the user "xx" rather than the user "root"

Comment: By the way, why azure want to forbidden me to ssh as root user? If I can not `ssh root@xxx` , how should I automatic manage my server? Looks like there is no other way more secure than `ssh root@xxx` with ssh public key with automatic management. Easy guess ssh username?

Comment: ssh as root is big no-no, from a security standpoint, so I'm thinking this is why you're getting that error, as Azure are trying to comply with basic security best practices.

Comment: @schaiba so what should I do it with automatic management? Write a tool that work as `ssh -c xxx@xxx sudo 'xxx'`? and make the username same again and again? that command just have too much escapes, I have to use a tool to escapes for me.

Answer (score 1):

There is a cloud-init option 'disable_root_opts'. By default, this is the variable that contains the "Please login as $USER".

```
/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/config/schemas/schema-cloud-config-v1.json:2855:          "default": "``no-port-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,command=\"echo 'Please login as the user \\\"$USER\\\" rather than the user \\\"$DISABLE_USER\\\".';echo;sleep 10;exit 142\"``",
/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/config/schemas/schema-cloud-config-v1.json:2856:          "description": "Disable root login options.  If ``disable_root_opts`` is specified and contains the string ``$USER``, it will be replaced with the username of the default user. Default: ``no-port-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,command=\"echo 'Please login as the user \\\"$USER\\\" rather than the user \\\"$DISABLE_USER\\\".';echo;sleep 10;exit 142\"``"
```

https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/modules.html#ssh

Just set that variable as an empty string, and it should no longer add the following to the root user's /root/.ssh/authorized_keys on first boot.

```
no-port-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,command="echo 'Please login as the user \"ubuntu\" rather than the user \"root\".';echo;sleep 10;exit 142"
```

Comment: sorry, but it is not my situation. I can only start a server with `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys` already looks like in the question. I need fix it with ssh with a none root account automatic.

Answer (score 0):

```
ssh -C -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ConnectTimeout=10 xxxYourServerUsername@xxxYourServerIp 'sudo bash -c '"'"'umask 077 && mkdir -p .ssh && echo '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'xxxYourSshPublicKey'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"' > /root/.ssh/authorized_keys'"'"''
```

Replace xxxYourServerIp with your server ip. Replace xxxYourServerUsername with your server username .Replace xxxYourSshPublicKey with your SshPublicKey content (should like ssh-rsa xxx root@xxx)

I think this is the secure and automatic way to do it, it should be secure then [how to enable root ssh public key login with no root account and sshpass and sudo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/551876/how-to-enable-root-ssh-public-key-login-with-no-root-account-and-sshpass-and-sud)

Comment: Oh lord, are you sure that quoting is correct? Seems a bit excessive.

Comment: It works, and I wrote a tool to do the quoting...You can get the escape rule from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250079/how-to-escape-single-quotes-within-single-quoted-strings